# JDK 8u31 doesn't install

Tags: java, netbeans, java-8

I'm trying to install JDK 8u31 for win 7 so that I can use NetBeans. However, when it asks for usual permissions from my user account and I click yes, nothing happens. No installer initialization, no error message. Help? Will provide information as necessary.

Comment: Did you download `jdk-8u31-windows-x64.exe` from this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) ? Try running your `.exe` as an Administrator

Comment: I did, and running as administrator didn't work either.

Comment: Is it your own system or some work pc ? One possibility is that you may not have admin rights to install anything. Did you try with some other installer like notepad++ or something else ?

Comment: It's my personal system

Comment: What about other installers ? Are you able to install anyother exe ?

Comment: Yes. The JDK is the only thing giving me trouble.